# WebDriver Selenium API: error running compiled .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I finished writing my test for FirefoxDriver, and compiled to a runnable jar packaging all the required libraries into the single test.jar file.

while running java Tester.jar I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main"

Could not find the main class: Tester.jar

but Tester.java has a main class.

How to fix this ?

Comment: How are you attempting to run the file? You should be running it like: java -jar Tester.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it with java -jar "Tester.jar".